# Dynamic Order By Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

The following order by query does not do any ordering for some reason. Am I doing this correctly? It only does a select, no ordering is applied at all.

```
var orders = (from order in db.GridExampleTable    
                      select order);
switch (sortBy)
        {
            default: orders.OrderBy(o => o.UnitPrice);
                break;
            case "CustomerName":
                if (sortDir == "asc")
                 orders.OrderBy(o => o.CustomerName);
                else
                    orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.CustomerName);
                  break;

        }
```

Comment: (Tip: There is *no* IEnumerable or IQueryable method that intrinsically modifies the initial sequence/object - use the *return value* of all such methods.)

Answer (score 3):

you are not collecting the results of your order. you need

```
orders = orders.OrderBy(o=>o.UnitPrice);
```

etc.

Comment: @GregCzechowicz you should mark one of these as the answer to help other who may have a similar issue find the right help :)

Answer (score 1):

.OrderBy returns an IOrderedEnumerable, it does not sort the original enumerable returned from your query.

Comment: thank you much, so I can have this sorted? Is it not possible this way?