# Passing parameters from view to entity framework OrderBy query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm wondering how i can perform an ascending and descending query from a view.  My current view is as below:

[image]

I understand i can order the view using the following:

```
Dim retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.User = userLoggedIn.Id).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()
```

I wish to pass the column heading and ascending or descending to the method from an action link i guess? (up and down arrow located near each heading).

OrderBy() does not accept a string.... can anyone help please? thank you

Controller:

```
   ' GET: Dashboard
    <Authorize(Roles:="Admin, Employee, User")>
    Function Index() As ActionResult

        Dim context = New ApplicationDbContext()
        Dim UserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(context))
        Dim userLoggedIn = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
        Dim retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.User = userLoggedIn.Id).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()

        Dim BuildsVM = retrieveOrders.[Select](Function(build) New DashboardBuilds() With {
        .BuildNumber = build.Id,
        .DateCreated = build.TimeAndDate,
        .MyRef = build.CustRef,
        .NetCost = build.TotalNet
        }).ToList()

        Dim today = DateTime.Today.Date
        Dim tomorrow = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1)
        Dim todaysBuild = retrieveOrders.Where(Function(build) build.TimeAndDate >= today And build.TimeAndDate <= tomorrow).ToList().Count()
        Dim monthlyBuild = retrieveOrders.Where(Function(build) build.TimeAndDate.Year = today.Year And build.TimeAndDate.Month = today.Month).ToList().Count()
        Dim yearlyBuild = retrieveOrders.Where(Function(build) build.TimeAndDate.Year = today.Year).ToList().Count()

        Dim total As Decimal = BuildsVM.Sum(Function(item) item.NetCost)
        Dim count As Integer = retrieveOrders.Count
        Dim Average As Decimal = 0.00

        If count > 0 Then
            Average = total / count
        End If


        Dim model = New GroupedDashBoardBuilds() With {
        .BuildInfos = BuildsVM,
        .TotalNet = Math.Round(total, 2),
        .AverageNet = Math.Round(Average, 2),
        .TotalUserBuild = count,
        .TotalUserBuildToday = todaysBuild,
        .TotalUserBuildMonth = monthlyBuild,
        .TotalUserBuildYear = yearlyBuild
        }

        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645267/dynamic-order-by-entity-framework you can always do your query, and order by later, i mean, first, get your data, then, switch case order ? Sorry it is C# in the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you'll be passing the field name and whether or not it is to be sorted ascending or descending into the controller:

```
Function Index(strColumnName As String, bolAscending As Boolean) As ActionResult
```

You can implement logic in a Select Case like this:

```
Dim retrieveOrders As List(Of PBBuilds) = Nothing

Select Case strColumnName
    Case "Build"
        If bolAscending Then
            retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.User = userLoggedIn.Id).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()
        Else
            retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.User = userLoggedIn.Id).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()
        End If
    Case "My Reference"
        If bolAscending Then
            retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.User = userLoggedIn.Id).OrderBy(Function(x) x.FieldRelatedToMyReference).ToList()
        Else
            retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.User = userLoggedIn.Id).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.FieldRelatedToMyReference).ToList()
        End If

    'Implement for Other Cases
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a neater way but i guess its not possible, i figured the above. I'm more interested in how i can create an html action helper to pass the information to the method

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the `OrderBy` running on the database, you can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<User, object>> ColumnAccessorMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<User, object>>()
{
    { "Build", user => user.ID },
    { "My Reference", user => user.MyReferenceProperty }
}

// etc...

context.MyTable.ToList().OrderBy(ColumnAccessorMap[strColumnName]);
```

or in VB.NET (Converted by hand, haven't used VB in a long time)

```
Dim ColumnAccessorMap as new Dictionary(of String, Object) From {{ "Build", Function(u) u.ID }, { "My Reference", Function(u) u.MyRefProperty }}

'... etc

context.MyTable.ToList().OrderBy(ColumnAccessorMap(strColumnName))
```

Essentially, mapping a column to an accessor function that tells the `OrderBy` what property to use when sorting.  Again, this won't work without the `.ToList` call before it, meaning that the sort happens locally, not in SQL.